# Is there a way to disable the right button in the topbar?

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Is there a way to disable the right button like here in the contacts app? [image: iOS Contact app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `enabled` option to false.

```
rightButtons: [
  {
    id: 'fertigBtn',
    text: 'Fertig',
    enabled: false
  }
]
```